# Oracle expdp compatibility issue

Tags: database, oracle, expdp

I have an Enterprise Oracle Database 12.2.0.1.0 installed. The output of 'show compatible' is 12.2.0.1.4.

When I try to run EXPDP with the correct credentials, I get the following error:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39021: Database compatibility version 12.2.0.1.4 is not supported.
```

After which EXPDP exists.
Should EXPDP's version be aligned with the 'compatible' parameter?

Comment: Set the value of `VERSION` parameter as `COMPATIBLE`. Oracle Data Pump checks the value of this parameter to determine the version of objects being exported.

Comment: @Incognito, but what if I don't know the version in advance, and running EXPDP via a script on different machines with different COMPATIBLE values ?